# Single Connection object at a time

Tags: java, sqlconnection, synchronize

**Basically i just want work only single sql connection at a time, wait other connection until first close.**

```
Class myConnection
{
        private static Connection con=null;
        public void getConnection()
        {
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"
                    + properties.getProperty("sqliteDatabase"));
        }
        public void closeConnection()
        {
         con.close();
        }
        public static void main(String s[]){
           myConnection m1=new myConnection();
           m1.getConnection();
          //m1 object using con variable
           myConnection m2=new myConnection(); 
          //m1.still executing query using con object
          m2.getConnection();
          //i should not allow m2 access con object till con object is null
}
```

i know it is not a right program. i just tried to explain what i want to do.
In short, i want single connection should work, wait another until connection is close.

Comment: try learning about Singleton pattern and DAO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/ for this purpose

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setUrl(url);
ds.setMaxActive(1);
```

now only one thread can get a connection from pool, others will block

Comment: Thanks, this is something new i learned. but company have already DAO pattern class. i have to just modify it in such way only one connection should work. After first connection close,automatically second connection should start.

Answer (score 0):

You can create pool of `Connection` object with size `1`. For example have : `ConnectionProvider` class.

Answer (score 0):

Implement signleton pattern on Connection Class.

```
 Class myConnection
{
        private static Connection con=null;
        public synchronized void getConnection()
        {
            con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"
                    + properties.getProperty("sqliteDatabase"));
        }
        public synchronized void closeConnection()
        {
         con.close();
        }
        public static void main(String s[]){
           myConnection m1=new myConnection();
           m1.getConnection();
          //m1 object using con variable
           myConnection m2=new myConnection(); 
          //m1.still executing query using con object
          m2.getConnection();
          //i should not allow m2 access con object till con object is null
}
```

Synchronized method can be called once at a time, No two objects can call synchronized method at the same time, If they call then one will have to wait for other.

Comment: I dont want to restrict the user to create another connection. instead i have to wait user until connection will close.

Comment: ok then implement synchronized method, i am updating my answer.